# Can't get the same result when I calculate in methods

Tags: java, oop, methods

I was learning methods, classes, objects and parameters. And decided to make my own program, but i get wrong result when I use parameters, objects and so on.
Here is the code:

```
class Resavanje {

    double temeA, temeB, temeC, povrsinaS;

    public Resavanje(double aX, double aY, double bX, double bY, double cX, double cY) {
        // Izracunavanje temena.
        temeA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bX - cX, 2) + Math.pow(bY - cY, 2));
        temeB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cX - aX, 2) + Math.pow(cY - aY, 2));
        temeC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aX - bX, 2) + Math.pow(aY - bY, 2));
    }

    double uzmiS() {
        return ((temeA + temeB + temeC) / 2);
    }

    // Povrsina trougla sa temenima
    double uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima() {
        return Math.sqrt(povrsinaS * (povrsinaS - temeA) * (povrsinaS - temeB) * (povrsinaS - temeC));
    }

}
```

and

```
public class PoblemTrougla {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resavanje objekat = new Resavanje(1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6);
        System.out.println(objekat.uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima());
    }

}
```

When I call method `objekat.uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima()` it should display: `9.000...7`
but result is `-0.0`

And if I use this in main method:

```
double s, p, a, b, c;
a = objekat.temeA;
b = objekat.temeB;
c = objekat.temeC;
s = (a + b + c) / 2;

p = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
```

I get result `9.000...7` which is correct result. Why I cant get the same result when I do calculation in methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double uzmiS()
{
    return ((temeA + temeB + temeC)/2);
}
```

this function is never run, which has the result of this: `s = (a+b+c)/2;` piece of your calculation never running.

try running something like:

```
povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC);
```

before you run your function `uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima()`

UPDATED for clarity

So, this statement:

```
objekat.uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima()
```

tells your computer to run this:

```
double uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima() {
     return Math.sqrt(povrsinaS *(povrsinaS-temeA)*(povrsinaS - temeB)*(povrsinaS- temeC));
}
```

code. You have a method similar to that one:

```
double uzmiS() {
    return ((temeA + temeB + temeC)/2);
}
```

Which is never run by your computer as no call to it is made!
Executing a command like `povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC);` tells your computer "hey, I'm going to run the uzimiS function and `return`that value into the variable `povrsinaS`.

This is equivalent to doing `s = (a+b+c)/2;` this step in the second example you provided.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand. Can you put some more code please ?
where to use this ? povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC);

Comment: Updated: I hope you have the tools, but I'm more than happy to show an explicit implementation if you need it!

Comment: yes, yes. I understand. In class Resavanje i added povrsinaS = uzmiS();
And when i try to call through object variable povrsinaS and print it's value it still has 0.0, how is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should track from the main method, it calls an constructor (which has 6 param)

```
Resavanje objekat = new Resavanje(1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6);
```

It will calculate 3 attributes of your objekat object, but it never calculate mean of them (in your case is povrsinaS attribute). So the uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima method will execute with value of povrsinaS is 0. To handle that, you can add this line to your constructor:

```
povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC);
```

or set it in your uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima method:

```
double uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima() {
    povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC); 
    return Math.sqrt(povrsinaS *(povrsinaS-temeA)*(povrsinaS - temeB)*(povrsinaS- temeC));
}
```

It will provide value of povrsinaS for uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima.

Comment: It doesnt work when i add that code you gave me... Cant figure out how should i do it, it reports error.

Comment: sorry, that's my fault, u just need to make clear change it to
`povrsinaS = uzmiS(temeA, temeB, temeC);`  to `this.povrsinaS = this.uzmiS();`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
povrsinaS = this.uzmiS();
```

to method `uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima()` like this:

```
class Resavanje {

    double temeA, temeB, temeC, povrsinaS;

    public Resavanje(double aX, double aY, double bX, double bY, double cX, double cY) {
        // Izracunavanje temena.
        temeA = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(bX - cX, 2) + Math.pow(bY - cY, 2));
        temeB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cX - aX, 2) + Math.pow(cY - aY, 2));
        temeC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(aX - bX, 2) + Math.pow(aY - bY, 2));
    }

    public double uzmiS() {
        return ((temeA + temeB + temeC) / 2);
    }

    // Povrsina trougla sa temenima
    double uzmiPovrsinuSaTemenima() {
        povrsinaS = this.uzmiS();           // <------ Add this line
        return Math.sqrt(povrsinaS * (povrsinaS - temeA) * (povrsinaS - temeB) * (povrsinaS - temeC));
    }

}
```

Your program will works, and return true result:

```
9.000000000000007
```

P/S: This is [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) in triangle. I love math, too.

Comment: Wow, it works now when i added that line.
Could you please tell me why when i use this code:
double temeA, temeB, temeC, povrsinaS = uzmiS();
povrsinaS still has value 0 when i gave it value from method ? 

Yeah it is Heron's formula, i enjoy math and trying to solve some tasks :)

Comment: In your case, after initialization `povrsinaS` ----> `povrsinaS = 0` ----> and it **does nothing more**. You must call method `uzmiS()`. And solution is add this line: `povrsinaS = this.uzmiS();` Meanwhile, `uzmiS()` **does something** what return the true value of `povrsinaS`

Comment: But wait... Can i make any method which will add value to povrsinaS ?
for example
void setPovrsinaS()
{
       povrsinaS = this.uzmiS(); // still get 0 ?
}

But when i add this line : povrsinaS = this.uzmiS();
in method where you told me it works, why it doesnt work in different method, void ?

Comment: @miljannet , It still works: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/4191520a94cbec7eb3f2#file-resavanje-java-L16-L22

Comment: I mean when i call
Resavanje objekat = new Resavanje(1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6);
System.out.println(objekat.povrsinaS); // variable still has 0, but we set it to have value which is returned in uzmiS method ?